# Can not set row value from table into array using Angular.js or Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I need one help.I need to set some value into array after index is changing using Angular.js.I am explaining my code below.

```
<tr ng-repeat="d in days">
    <td>{{d.day_name}}</td>
    <td> <select class="form-control" id="catagory" ng-model="catagory" ng-options="cat.name for cat in listOfCatagory track by cat.value " ng-change="removeBorder('catagory',$index,catagory.value);">
     </select></td>
    <td>
        <select class="form-control" id="subcatagory[$index]" ng-model="subcatagory[$index]" ng-options="sub.name for sub in listOfSubCatagory[$index] track by sub.value " ng-change="setSubCatagory($index,subcatagory[$index].value);">
    <option value="">Select Subcategory</option>
    </select>

    </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="comment" id="comment" class="form-control oditek-form" placeholder="Add Comment" ng-model="comment[$index]" ng-keyup="comment($index,comment[$index]);"></td>
</tr>
<input type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="saveResturantDetails(billdata);"  id="saveData" value="Save"   style="margin-right:20px;"/>
```

I am collecting each row data like below.

```
var rowData = {};
 $scope.removeBorder = function(id, index, catvalue) {
     $scope.listOfSubCatagory[index] = [];
     var catdata = $.param({
         'action': 'subcat',
         'cat_id': catvalue
     });
     $http({
         method: 'POST',
         url: "php/customerInfo.php",
         data: catdata,
         headers: {
             'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
         }
     }).then(function successCallback(response) {
         angular.forEach(response.data, function(obj) {
             var data = {
                 'name': obj.subcat_name,
                 'value': obj.subcat_id
             };
             $scope.listOfSubCatagory[index].push(data);
         })
     }, function errorCallback(response) {})
     rowData['cat'] = catvalue;

 }
 $scope.setSubCatagory = function(index, subcatvalue) {
     rowData['subcat'] = subcatvalue;
     console.log('sub cat', rowData);
 }
 $scope.comment = function(index, comment) {
     rowData['comment'] = comment;
 }
```

Here i need to push all row selected value into a array in row wise.Please help me.

Comment: Could you brief your question?

Comment: @Vasanth : Suppose i selected some data from each row of the table and clicked on save button.All data should collected and save into array like this `var arrData=[{'cat':1,'subcat':12,'comment':hii},{'cat':2,'subcat':22,'comment':hii},....]`.

Comment: Have a flag IsSelected in your SubCatagory Model. On setSubCatagory Make this flag true. On Submit click iterate through the List of SubCatagory and add the isSelected is true model to new array

Comment: @Vasanth : Can you write your answer please?

Answer (score 0):

Create 3 string objects var Category, var SubCategory and var Comment.

On Save function push the three variables to Rowdata array:

`rowData.push({Cat:Category, SubCat:SubCategory , Comment:Comment});`

Comment: Will it be fetch all row selected data..?

Comment: What this `var Category, var SubCategory and var Comment.` will contain.

Comment: Instead of rowData['cat'] assign to var Category variable like wise for  subcat & comment. On save assign this 3 variable value to a array object as shown above